# Present a UIViewController from a SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, skscene

I have a GameViewController that presents a SKScene, and I want to present a new UIViewController from that SKScene, I have been searching for a long time, and I just can't find an answer.

Comment: look up how to delegate UIViewContollers,  then what you do is you have the Scene tell the View a transition is needed,  View tells the View Controller,  View Controller performs the action

Comment: that should probably be handled via delegation - the GameViewController tells the scene he is the one responsible for any callbacks, the scene tells the GVC that it is somehow completed and the GVC then decides that presenting a scene is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to show/present a UIViewController from an SKScene?

If yes, you would need to use a Segue. I used this in my SKScene in my game to get back to the menu, which is

```
var vc: UIViewController = UIViewController()
vc = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
self.viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToMenu", sender: vc)
```

Am I off topic? If yes please tell me and I will try to change my answer (instead of voting down), as I am unsure of what you want to do exactly.

Comment: That didn't work for me at the beginning, but then i changed the
self.viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToMenu", sender: vc)
to:
vc.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToMenu", sender: vc) it worked perfectly for me, so thanks for leading me in the right direction ;)